# Why is my logging Web Service Endpoint for Safari Push Notifications receving blank requests with no error message

Tags: ios, web-services, apple-push-notifications

**Background**

I am setting up a basic web service to send safari push notifications.  I have set up my apple certificate and push package endpoint.  However when I make a call to get the push package it fails and the user does not get a prompt requestion permission.  This doesn't surprise me, the real issue is that I am not getting a failure message at my logging endpoint so that I can determine what the issue is.

**What I have tried**

I have added logging at both the push package request and log level and I know these are being triggered as I log a timestamp when they are called.  However the logging message for my webServiceURL/version/log is logging that there is no content.  If I test the log api with postman I successfully log the entire message, but I only ever get an empty value when called via my requestPermission call.

Note: I am getting the content with this command:

```
print_r($_REQUEST, true)
```

Which returns array()

**What is needed**

To figure out how to log error messages so I can debug issues.

Comment: Please check that your API URLs don't redirect in any way. I've had a simple domain to www.domain redirect and that messed it up.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot know the exact reason for this issue but I solved it by moving my endpoints into one file at the same level.  Previously I had my directory structure of /webServiceURL/v1/pushPackages/pushid and /webService/v1/log.  I removed these directories and used one file reading the path to determine the action.  After I did this logging started working.